# Microsoft Excel 2010 Autoshape "Adjustments" Property (msoShapeTrapezoid)

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is there a reference available anywhere that details what each "`adjustment property`" does for the various **Autoshape objects** available in **Excel 2010**?

My specific problem is that I am programatically inserting an msoShapeTrapezoid autoshape onto a worksheet with:

```
.AddShape(msoShapeTrapezoid, Left, Top, Width, Height)
```

... which defines the rectangular extent of the trapezoid. Then I am attempting to use:

```
shpTrapezoid.Adjustments(1) = ValueX
```

to set the size of the top of the trapezoid (the equivalent of adjusting the single handle on the autoshape manually I guess), but I can't work out what this adjustment property represents (although I have figured out that a value of `0` makes the trapezoid a rectangle).

So given I know the size of the base of the trapezoid, the size of the top of the trapezoid and the height of the trapezoid I want to draw (and that it is symmetrical), **what does ValueX have to be to correctly define it on the screen?**

Comment: Have you seen this? If not, does it help? <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213688(v=office.11).aspx>

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that but it doesn't really help. From that information it looks like the linear adjustment for the msoShapeTrapezoid should run from `0` to `0.5` (i.e. rectangle -> triangle at the extremes) but I have tried dragging the handle while recording a macro and the values come out in excess of 0.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, sorry for my poor english...

I have been struggling with this problem during a couple of hours and I have found that the adjustment for the msoShapeTrapezoid is a coefficient that must be multiplied by the width of the form if the width is less than the height or by the height of the form if the height is less than the width.

This also explains why this adjustment can be more than 0.5  (if the height of the form is less than its width, the adjustment can be more than 0.5: the max value is width divided by height but in the other case the max value is 0.5 ).

So if you want to draw a trapezoid, the adjustment must be calculated like this: subtract the top of the trapezoid to the base, divide by 2 the result and divide the new result by the height of the trapezoid if the height is less than its width or by its width in the other case.

This also applies to the msoShapeParallelogramm ;the adjustment must be multiplied by the Min(Width;Height).

There are a lot of little bugs in these AutoShapes... (for example, the msoShapeRegularPentagone is not a regular pentagon... but the base is calculated by multiplying the width of the form by the Golden Ratio minus 1 and the "elevation " of the points located on the left and right side of the form is also equal  to the GoldenRation minus 1 multiplied by the width of the form: the result is near to a regular pentagon but it is not)

Answer (score 1):

The lack of AutoShape-specific documentation on this topic is disappointing, right?  Even more frustrating: the values of an AutoShape's various `.Adjustments` don't appear in the Locals window; the only useful information we can see is the `.Count`.

This lead me to write the following utility sub that I keep adding to whenever I investigate another AutoShape.

```
'Usage: select AutoShape in question then run this...
Sub AutoShapeAdjustments()
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim SHP As Shape
    Set SHP = Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With SHP
        For ii = 1 To .Adjustments.Count
            Debug.Print "Adj# " & ii & " ="; .Adjustments(ii)
        Next ii

        Stop 'to review IW contents & update/add to `Select Case` block

        Select Case .AutoShapeType

        Case msoShapeArc
            .Adjustments(1) = 135 'tail angle; CW from 0 = east
            .Adjustments(2) = 45 'arrow angle
        Case msoShapeCircularArrow
            .Adjustments(1) = 0.1 'arrow throat thickness (1 & 3 share a handle)
            .Adjustments(2) = 15 'arrow head length
            .Adjustments(3) = 45 'revolution angle, arrow; CW from 0 = east
            .Adjustments(4) = 135 'revolution angle, tail
            .Adjustments(5) = 0.1 'arrow head width excl. throat
        Case msoShapeDownArrow, msoShapeUpArrow, msoShapeRightArrow, msoShapeLeftArrow
            .Adjustments(1) = 0.5 'arrow throat thickness
            .Adjustments(2) = 0.5 'arrow head length

        End Select
    End With

    If MsgBox("Clear Immediate Window?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then
        Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {BACKSPACE}"
    Else
        Debug.Print "--------------------"
    End If

End Sub
```

I run it several times to figure out, and make note of, what each `.Adjustment` does.  Then once I've fine-tuned a set of values I paste them into the code I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it's relevant to my current project and I thought I'd throw in the solution I found-
For my project I wanted to define Width, Height, and TopWidth. With that, the value passed to the adjustment property is:

```
shpTrapezoid.Adjustments(1) = (Width - TopWidth)/(2 * Height)
```

This should work no matter which is bigger (Height or Width) since presumably your TopWidth is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

In case it might help anyone in the future, this is my method to add a trapezoid

```
Function AddTrapezoid(wks As Worksheet, sglCentre As Single, sglTop As Single, _
        sglWidthTop As Single, sglWidthBottom As Single, sglHeight As Single) As Shape
    Set AddTrapezoid = wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeTrapezoid, sglCentre - sglWidthBottom / 2, _
            sglTop, sglWidthBottom, sglHeight)
    AddTrapezoid.Adjustments.Item(1) = (sglWidthBottom - sglWidthTop) / 2# / _
            IIf(sglHeight < sglWidthBottom, sglHeight, sglWidthBottom)
End Function
```

This works whether the height or width is greatest, matches the answer provided by @sherco40